# Consumer Report for Lab Equipment

Tags: materials, reference-request

I'm just wondering if anybody here knows of a Consumer-Report-like publication for lab equipment. Something that would give the specifics, as, for example, the flow rate of a distilling condenser, etc.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the specific example you mention depends more on factors you control than on the condenser: how much heat you give it, what solvent you are distilling, what is the external pressure, are you distilling a compound that is relatively pure or is it part of a complex mixture, etc.

Comment: My advisor tells us to always ask the sales rep for references, other people who purchase and used that equipment. You can ask them how it works. If they won't give a reference, don't buy it. This stuff is mostly learned through experience and talking with other scientists.